# In Joint.js can not find graph.getSources() in graph object

Tags: jointjs

I am using jointjs and i am referring their official API tutorial http://jointjs.com/api . But some of the methods on graph objects like getsources , ispredecessor is not found.

I have linked to 0.95 version hoping that its the latest on given on their site. Not sure if i am missing something.

Its an awesome framework and would like say my big thanks to the team. Will be buying their paid version soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out was using older version. From github i got 0.96 looks like they did not update their site.